# Order results of CLGeoCoder geocodeAddressString by nearest location

Tags: ios, ios6, geolocation, geocoding

I'm sure that I can figure this out based on code that I have implemented in PHP in the past, but I was hoping that someone has either done this and can provide an example or knows of a way to use the iOS SDK to accomplish it.

Here's my relevant code:

```
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
CLLocationDistance dist = _searchDistance;
CLLocationCoordinate2D point = self.locationManager.location.coordinate;
CLRegion *region = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:point radius:dist identifier:@"Hint Region"];
[geocoder geocodeAddressString:address inRegion:region completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
{
     if( error )
     {
        // Push errors to the user
     }
     else
     {
        NSLog( [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Got results: %@", placemarks] );
     }
 }];
```

This pushes to the log something like the following:

```
(
    "300 Oak St, Phoenix, OR  97535-5722, United States @ <+42.26953820,-122.81554259> +/- 100.00m, region (identifier <+42.26953820,-122.81554106> radius 27.00) <+42.26953820,-122.81554106> radius 27.00m",
    "300 Oak St, Ashland, OR  97520, United States @ <+42.19955633,-122.71289484> +/- 100.00m, region (identifier <+42.19955633,-122.71289484> radius 138.42) <+42.19955633,-122.71289484> radius 138.42m",
    "300 Oak St, Jacksonville, OR  97530, United States @ <+42.31236366,-122.97179130> +/- 100.00m, region (identifier <+42.31236366,-122.97179130> radius 138.33) <+42.31236366,-122.97179130> radius 138.33m",
    "300 Oak St, Central Point, OR  97502, United States @ <+42.37422514,-122.91427182> +/- 100.00m, region (identifier <+42.37422514,-122.91427182> radius 138.29) <+42.37422514,-122.91427182> radius 138.29m",
    "300 Oak St, Rogue River, OR  97537, United States @ <+42.43621216,-123.16864522> +/- 100.00m, region (identifier <+42.43621216,-123.16864522> radius 138.24) <+42.43621216,-123.16864522> radius 138.24m"
)
```

In this case, the second result is the closest to my current location. I would like to have this list ordered by matches that are closest to my current location. I'm reasonably confident that I know how to do the math to figure out which location is closest, but I was hoping for a shortcut. Iterating through this array and sorting the results is going to be somewhat heavy, so I'd like to avoid that if possible.

**EDIT (complete answer):**

@Akash gave me the bit of information I was seeking, so I marked that answer as the correct one. If anyone is interested in sorting the results (rather than just getting the closest location), I put the unsorted results into an `NSDictionary` using the distance as a key, then used `compare` to sort the keys and then put the original `placemark` array elements into an output array ordered by the key to which they were associated in the `NSDictionary`. Here's the complete code (and the complete answer to my question):

```
-(NSMutableArray *)distanceSortPlacemarks:(NSArray *)inputArray fromLocation:(CLLocation *)originLocation
{
    NSMutableArray *returnValue = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[inputArray count]];

    NSMutableDictionary *sortDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:[inputArray count]];
    for( int i = 0; i < [inputArray count]; i++ )
    {
        CLPlacemark *currentPlacemark = [inputArray objectAtIndex:i];

        [sortDictionary
         setObject:currentPlacemark
         forKey:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[currentPlacemark.location distanceFromLocation:originLocation]]
         ];
    }

    NSArray *sortedKeys = [[sortDictionary allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

    for( int i = 0; i < [sortedKeys count]; i++ )
    {
        CLPlacemark *currentPlacemark = [sortDictionary objectForKey:[sortedKeys objectAtIndex:i]];
        [returnValue insertObject:currentPlacemark atIndex:i];
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

I know this could be a little tighter (some of the variables aren't absolutely necessary), but I tend to err on the side of making code easier to understand at quick glance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try getting distance of your current location from `CLLocation` in each `CLPlacemark` as follows :

```
for(int i = 0; i < placemarks.count; i++)
{
    double distance = [placemarks[i].location distanceFromLocation:yourCurrentLocation];

    if(i == 0)
    {
        indexOfClosestLocation = i;
        distanceFromClosestLocation = distance;
    }
    else
    {
        if(distance < distanceFromClosestLocation)
        {
            distanceFromClosestLocation = distance;
            indexOfClosestLocation = i;
        }
    }
}
```

After executing this code you have index of closest `CLLocation` in `placemarks` array and distance to it in `meters`.

Comment: `distanceFromLocation` is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!